# HTML, PHP, MYSQL, Upload image and save it's url into database

Tags: php, mysql, html

So i have a mysql database and this is what is contains for each row:

`ID | title | subtitle | image | username`

Id = Auto

Title is a textbox on site

subtitle is a textbox on site

image you upload it

username is a textbox.

How can i for the image insert the uploaded url where it uploads

being my website.com/uploads

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp has a nice example. You can parse `$_FILES["file"]["name"]` and save it to the image column in DB

Comment: what is the `type` of the image column? Is it a `BLOB` where you want to store the image data? Or is it a `VARCHAR` column and you want to save the uploaded image somewhere in disk and save the path in this column?

Comment: its a VARCHAR  want to save the uploaded image somewhere in disk and save the path in this column

Answer (score 2):

You can just upload it as usual, via `$_FILES`, then store the path in the database. Then, set the user's image source equal to that value.

Answer (score 2):

you don't save the actual image to the database. rather you save the image name (`$_FILES["file"]["name"]`) in the database, and the image in a file. then when you want to refer to the image in your website, you refer to the file path of the image i.e.

```
$image_path = 'images/'
$image_source = $image_path . $_FILES["file"]["name"]
```

NOTE: `$_FILES["file"]["name"]` will return something like this: name.extension